# Difficulty implementing some kind of backwards compatibility in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, trigger

I'm facing an issue with implementing a rule or trigger in PostgreSQL to handle inserts into a table where one of the column types (`a`) has been changed and old queries . I've tried a few approaches, but I haven't been able to achieve the desired behavior.

Here's a simplified version of my scenario:

I have a table `t1` with columns `a` and `b`:

```sql
CREATE TABLE t1 (
    a int,
    b int
);
```

I want to allow queries that come with another type for column `a`, such as a string, and replace it with another value, say 0. However, if an integer value is inserted, it should be preserved without modification.

I've tried using a rule and trigger function, but I'm encountering issues with each approach:

1. **Rule**: I tried creating a rule to intercept inserts and modify the value of column `a` if it's not an integer. However, I faced issues with infinite recursion and the rule not being triggered for invalid inputs:

```sql
CREATE RULE test_rule AS
    ON INSERT TO t1
    WHERE pg_typeof(NEW.a) <> 'integer'::regtype
    DO INSTEAD
        INSERT INTO t1 (a, b)
        VALUES (0, NEW.b)
```

```sql
postgres=# insert into t1 (select 'x',1);
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type integer: "x"
LINE 1: insert into t1 (select 'x',1);
                               ^
postgres=# insert into t1 (select 1,1);
ERROR:  infinite recursion detected in rules for relation "t1"
```

2. **Trigger Function**: I attempted to use a trigger function to check the data type of the inserted value and modify it accordingly. While this approach worked for valid inputs, it didn't handle invalid inputs as expected.

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insert_default_a_if_non_integer()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS
$$
BEGIN
    IF pg_typeof(NEW.a) <> 'integer'::regtype THEN
        NEW.a := 0;  -- or any default value you prefer
    END IF;
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER t1_insert_trigger
BEFORE INSERT ON t1
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE FUNCTION insert_default_a_if_non_integer();
```

```sql
postgres=# insert into t1 (select 1,1);
INSERT 0 1
postgres=# insert into t1 (select 'x',1);
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type integer: "x"
LINE 1: insert into t1 (select 'x',1);
                               ^
```

Could someone please provide guidance on the best approach to achieve my requirement? Any insights or alternative solutions would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your attempts fail at the statement compilation stage, before they begin executing and cause the rewrite rule or trigger to activate.

One way to address your predicament is to create a view with columns compatible with your now incorrect insert statements and define an `instead of` trigger on that view.

Comment: ... or have the application run different queries, depending on the schema version. That might be the simplest way.